# why does easy_install install 64x when I ask for 32x

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, psycopg2

Is it trying to be "helpful"?

I'm running win 8 64x. I need to install psycopg 32x. I use the command as noted [in the heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/psycopg2-windows)

```
easy_install http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/2.4.6/psycopg2-2.4.6.win32-py2.7-pg9.2.2-release.exe
```

Then I see it installs

```
Installed \venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.4.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
```

This is the 64x version, not the 32x I need.

Later I get error

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I'm thinking that perhaps the windows 32x installer for psycopg is labelled wrong but that's unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `easy_install` that is installed by the 32bit version of cpython. (easy_install can work with not only 32bit and 64bit version of cpython, but other implementations of python like pypy .. )

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
python distribute_setup.py <= change this line to make use of 32bit version of cpython
```

Comment: do I need to install python 2.7 32x?

Comment: If you want 32bit package to be installed, yes

Comment: I just want to deploy my django python app to heroku. So that only works with 32x python

Comment: but when I donwload the 32x version of psycopg2 via the link, how can it install the 64x? it doesn't even have the binaries for it...